# Recurring payments subscriptions with Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I´m trying to develop a link for a web site to redirect the logged user to a checkout process that allow recurring payments via Paypal using its credit cards.
I´ve read Paypal documentation regarding subscriptions and I have some questions:

1. There is a warning message telling:
   **"The use of the Paypal REST /payments APIs to accept credit card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card payments with Braintree Direct".**

   Is it true?. Do I have to use some Braintree REST API or SDK to let user to 
   put credit card information?
2. After users approve agreements, how can I get credit card expiration dates to inform whether some are close to expire.?

Any help or clarification would be appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Roberto, what you are reading is different than what you are trying to do. You are trying to accept recurring payments using PayPal checkout with the option for cutomers to pay via a credit card, yes?

Comment: Hi GeekNinja!. I´ve just was able to create an agreement for a recurring payment using REST API using dummy credit cards and it worked as expected. My worry now is how can a buyer be notified whether his/her credit card is close to expire and the agreement possibly cancel?. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it may work for sandbox, however when you flip to a live endpoint with live rest creds; secret and client; credit cards will not work; hence the restriction message you received. But your question denotes 'pay via PayPal'; which I assumed is PayPal hosted landing page.

Comment: you should check Paypal Subscription API here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/#